# Inheriting DefaultContractResolver and treating referenced entities differently

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to serialize only changed properties. I was managed to do it for the root type, but it contains references to other objects to be serialized (that might even be of the same type).

This is my interface and ContractResolver:

```
public interface ISelectiveJsonSerialize
{
    IList<string> PropertiesToSerialize { get; }
}

public class JsonSelectiveSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly IList<string> _propertiesToSerialize;

    public JsonSelectiveSerializeContractResolver(IList<string> propertiesToSerialize)
    {
        _propertiesToSerialize = propertiesToSerialize;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization).Where(p => _propertiesToSerialize.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();
    }
}
```

The property PropertiesToSerialize will have a list of property names that received a value.

This is how I serialize:

```
        string result = "";
        if (val is ISelectiveJsonSerialize)
        {
            // Don't serialize all properties
            var resolver = new JsonSelectiveSerializeContractResolver(((ISelectiveJsonSerialize)val).PropertiesToSerialize);
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = resolver };
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(val, Formatting.None, settings);
        }
        else
        {
            // Default serialization
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(val);
        }

        return result;
```

And this is an example of a type I can serialize:

```
public class Category : BaseType
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            PropertiesToSerialize.Add("Name");
        }
    }

    private Category _category;
    public Category Category
    {
        get { return _category; }
        set
        {
            _category = value;
            PropertiesToSerialize.Add("Category");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can understand, If I only set a category for my root type which has a name, it won't serialize the name because the root PropertiesToSerialize doesn't contain "Name", If it would of it would serialize the empty name of the root entity.

Help?

Comment: I'm thinking of some combination between the ContractResolver to JsonConverter but have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Have you ever considered using view models?

Comment: How will view models be different? Those classes are not entities, they can be treated as view models, I can do whatever I want with them, this is why added that list of altered properties to be serialized. So how can a view model help me?

Comment: The `Category` class you have shown is very far from something I would ever call a view model. It is deriving from some base type (`BaseType` in your case) and the getters of your properties contain some C# code (things like `PropertiesToSerialize.Add`).

Comment: I didn't say it is, I said it might as well be.. but you still didn't say why would a view model be different? how can I use the logic I introduced in my question without adding the properties to the PropertiesToSerialized list?

Comment: You would introduce this logic in the mapping layer between your domain model and view model.

Comment: Still no satisfying answer =\

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the [conditional property serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm) functionality of Json.NET to add a test to determine whether a given property has been modified before serializing it:

```
public class JsonSelectiveSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        var shouldSerialize = property.ShouldSerialize;
        var name = property.PropertyName;
        property.ShouldSerialize = (o) =>
        {
            var selectiveSerialize = o as ISelectiveJsonSerialize;
            if (selectiveSerialize != null)
            {
                if (!selectiveSerialize.PropertiesToSerialize.Contains(name))
                    return false;
            }
            return shouldSerialize == null || shouldSerialize(o);
        };

        return property;
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tZJ2Cy).