# Ignore property during serialization if it is not set explicity

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Consider a bool value "`IsReady`"

I can set this as nullable and ignore this during serialization by  `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`
or I can set the `DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`

The problem here is if I need to change the the property to nullable then there are hundreds of property I need to do. Given the situation I don't think I will be allowed to do this as this will also require code change in other modules too.

The problem with second approach is the in real time there are instances where `IsReady` will be `false` and I want it to be serialized.

So I am not sure what could be the best approach here.

I would like to know if there any way to avoid serializing a property if it is null or was not set explicitly in the code.

I am using json.net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387755/can-javascriptserializer-exclude-properties-with-null-default-values Did you check this question ?

Comment: @mybirthname I don't want to ignore default value is it is set explicitly.

Comment: Create another class which have same properties. And set/remove `ignore` attributes for your specific scenario.

Comment: If you only want to serialize a property if it has been set explicitly, you're going to need to track changes made to it in your code somehow, since it is a property of the *history* of your object, not the *current state* of the object.  Making the underlying field be nullable is one possibility.  Another is adding an `xxxSpecified` property as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223335/how-to-force-newtonsoft-json-to-serialize-all-properties-strange-behavior-with/39224495#39224495).

Comment: Does your class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @dbc No. Sorry, I am not aware of this interface.

Comment: Seems very similar to this: [Inheriting DefaultContractResolver and treating referenced entities differently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16657918/3744182).